# Add method to the Django CMS Page Model

Tags: python, django, django-cms

**Problem/Gap**

The Django CMS documentation clearly describes the process for [extending the Page and Title Models](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/extending_page_title.html).
However, documentation on the possibility of adding a method such as the property method below is lacking, or I can't seem to find it.

> Note: The example provided works perfectly when I include it directly
> under the Django CMS `Page` model. This is not the preferred way of
> course.

**Question**

Say I want to add the below method to the Page (cms.models.pagemodel.Page) or Title Model (assuming they are likely to follow the same process) *outside the CMS app*. How can this be achieved?

```
    @property
    def my_custom_page_property(self):
        try:
            logger.info(f'Working....')
            return {}

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f'Error: {e}')
            return {}
```

**Attempt**

In a seperate app I added the code below, and migrated. The image field is properly configured and works fine. The method however doesn't seem to return anything.

```
from cms.extensions import PageExtension
from cms.extensions.extension_pool import extension_pool

class MyCustomExtension(PageExtension):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image,
                              on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                              default=None,
                              blank=True,
                              null=True)

    @property
    def my_custom_page_property(self):
        ..
```

Comment: How would you access this property? I've never tried it, but extending the page with your `PageExtension` would be the way I'd try it first. That `image` field becomes available in your templates, so it'd make sense that you could also access a property.

Comment: I can access this property through a template tag for instance, and then do something like `if hasattr(obj, 'my_custom_page_property'):`

Comment: [django-strucutred-data](https://github.com/dmptrluke/django-structured-data/blob/master/structured_data/templatetags/jsonld.py) is a perfect use-case example

Answer (score 0):

This is possible - I've set it up with a page extension I use for adding images to pages.

So taking the example;

```
class PageImage(PageExtension):
    """Add images to pages"""

    image = models.FileField(
        verbose_name=_("Image"),
        upload_to=upload_to("page_images"),
        validators=[validate_data_size, validate_file_name],
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    gallery = models.ForeignKey(
        to="filer.Folder",
        verbose_name=_("Image gallery"),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="page_gallery",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )

    @property
    def test_prop(self):
        return "Hello world"

    class Meta:
        app_label = "cms_extras"
        verbose_name = _("CMS Page Image")
        verbose_name_plural = _("CMS Page Images")


extension_pool.register(PageImage)
```

Then in the template I've got;

```
        <div class="hero" style="background: url({% if request.current_page.pageimage.image %}{{ request.current_page.pageimage.image.url }}{% endif %}) center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
            <div class="hero__text-wrapper">
                <h1>{% if request.current_page.pageimage.image %}{{ request.current_page.pageimage.test_prop }}{% endif %}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This `test_prop` is being rendered to the page.

Comment: If this works then there is something I am missing. I will check.